# Image filter to cartoonize and colorize

Tags: java, php, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm trying to make a specific image filter, processing a picture to cartoonize and change the colors.

Here you can see the original and the expected result:
http://codingfocus.com/ieffect.jpg

I'm not sure which will be a good approach, I started with a grayscale, posterize and color replacement ranges based on how dark is every pixel, but the result is pretty pixelated and not near to what I would like to obtain.
http://codingfocus.com/test3.jpg

I'm currently trying both with php gd, imagemagick and jhlabs library for java.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick, this gives somewhat similar effect.

Input:

[image]

```
convert faces.jpg -colorspace gray -kuwahara 3 -unsharp 0x2+4+0 \( xc:blue xc:red xc:yellow +append \) -clut result.jpg
```

[image]

Or without the 3 color lookup table:

```
convert faces.jpg -kuwahara 3 -unsharp 0x2+4+0 result2.jpg
```

[image]

See http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=26480. But it requires version 6.8.9.9 or higher for the kuwahara filter.

Comment: This is perfect and I already use some scripts of your awesome site. Thank you!

Comment: I just created a new script, toonizarro, to do the above effect.

Comment: It's curious how the whole internet is in SO, I was looking through all your scripts a week ago for an effect like this one and I didn't think the author would like to help me that much. Thanks again!

Comment: When you first asked the question, I did not have an answer. But experimentation found an interesting though not the same effect and I thought it was good enough for a script. I just finished it yesterday. I am always looking for ideas for new scripts. Feel free to contact me with any ideas. If I think I can do it I will try.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of replacing with a range of grayscale, convert in HSV color space and use a range based on channel H (hue).

If you want to remove the pixelated effect you can simply blur the result, or pheraps before the posterize effect too to remove the noise.

Comment: The hard part is not the coloring. You can use a 3 color smooth lookup table clut on a grayscale version of your image in ImageMagick. The hard part is changing the shape of your image to make it into a caricature. I do not know how to do that kind of effect. However, you can reduce the number of colors in the the grayscale image using -colorize, -posterize or my script kmeans. I also have other cartooning scripts at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.html. They are bash unix shell scripts.